# Is there a way to kill a process automatically by filtering its name?

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, virus

I have a process in my Task Manager, which is end-able, but keeps starting up again.

No Anti Virus has found this ad-ware virus yet, and I'm starting to think the only way to stop it from opening is to filter out its name in a program.

> This is a very brief example of what I want

```
If process.XXX Alive = True;
      {
          Get process.XXX.PID;
          PID.End();
      }
```

Please ask me for any additional information.

> Edit: Changed `'id'` to `'pid'`

Comment: This is very industrious, however the assertive way to do this is, look up what it is, understand it and why its there, remove the process or remove it from startup or disable the service that is starting it ect ect ect.. if you don't need it, it shouldn't be on your pc,

Comment: If a process keeps starting up again and again, then it's either a service with automatic restart, or is being relaunched by another process. In a situation like this, I would load up `msconfig` and carefully check the non-MS "services" section, and also check any applications that run on Startup.

Comment: Creating a program that _polls_ for a process will certainly use a lot of system resources, and if you're on a laptop it will also drain your battery. The longer the delay between the polls the less it will affect the computer, however longer delays might make the application pointless (in this case). I suggest you follow what the others have already said and try to find what's starting it instead. In addition check the Task Scheduler as well for anything suspicious.

Comment: As indicated by others, this isn't the right approach. You should get rid of this program _after making sure you don't actually need it_. If the information in the previous comments isn't enough guidance for you to do so, you can ask this question on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), explain the problem in details (e.g., provide information about this specific executable, etc.), **and don't involve any coding requests** or else the question would probably be closed.

Comment: You don't need to write anything for this, it's a built-in capability: `wmic process where "name like '%notepad%'" call terminate`

Answer (score 0):

```
// Sub adware with the name of the process
// Do not include .exe in the process name
Process p[] = Process.GetProcessesByName("adware");

foreach(Process pr in p) pr.Kill();
```

Answer (score 0):

Internally Task Manager uses the Windows Management API. From the command line you can kill processes by name, using the built-in `wmic` windows management console program.

For example, this will kill all instances of notepad:

```
wmic process where "name like '%notepad%'" call terminate
```

It can do other things too:

```
wmic process where "name like '%notepad%'" get executablepath
```

Then you can find that file and delete it.

Note: To kill processes not owned by you, you must use an elevated command prompt.

Note 2: You don't say what the process is, so there is a danger that I am helping you destroy your system without realising it. Before doing this, find out what the executable path and command line are, and investigate whether they are actually problem software.

```
wmic process where "name like '%program%'" get executablepath,commandline
```